# The jsp does not show the value of variable

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have following class that send the value of name variable but the jsp does not show it.
It just show the hello world message

Employee.java

```
public class Employee {

    private String name;

    public Employee(){
       this.name = "Daniel";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
       this.name = name;
    }
```

Emp.java

```
public class Emp implements Controller {


private Employee empp;

protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

   @Override
     public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("empp:"+this.empp.getName());
        String myname = empp.getName();
        logger.info("Returning hello view");

    return new ModelAndView("emp.jsp","name",myname);  

     }
```

Emp.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <h2><c:out value="${name}"/></h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Also used the following**

```
@Override
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    System.out.println("empp:"+this.empp.getName());
    String myname = empp.getName();
    logger.info("Returning hello view");
    Map<String, Object> myModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    myModel.put("name", this.empp.getName());

return new ModelAndView("emp.jsp","model",myModel);
}
```

Emp.jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <h2><c:out value="${model.name}"/></h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

I used

```
<h1><%= pageContext.findAttribute("model.name") %></h1>
```

but it returns Null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the value of `employeeInstance.getName()` to ModelAndView. According to the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html), here's how to do so:

```
@Override
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        logger.info("Returning hello view");
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.addObject("name", employeeInstance.getName());
        modelAndView.setViewName("Emp.jsp");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Being controller an interface, their contant variables can't change, it's just a read-only value. Is the variable name in the Interface Controller?

Answer (score 0):

If none of these works just use

request.setParameter in java

and

response.getParameter in jsp

Answer (score 0):

you should add this into your page head:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Or directly use EL:

```
 <h1>${model.name}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

The mistake in my case was I imported `org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView` instead of `org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView`. Using the latter solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make this small modification in your jsp

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <h2>/${name.getName()}</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```